# How To Parse Blogger Rss feed Using Javascript and get output on a HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, blogger

I want to parse my blogger feed from below RSS Link 
https://www.universalmanual.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss.
https://www.universalmanual.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?alt=rss

.I want to show that parsed data on a plan HTML Page.
Is there any method to extract it data using javascript.
Usign JSON I will get Title, author name and summary but didn't able to get images, how to add images in below code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mycallback(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
          var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
          break;
        }
      }
      var postimage = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
      var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
      var postAuthor = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
      var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
      var entryShort = postSummary.substring(0,400);
      var entryEnd = entryShort.lastIndexOf(" ");
      var postContent = entryShort.substring(0, entryEnd) + '...';
      var item = '<div class="wrapper"><img src=' + postimage + '><h3><a href=' + postUrl + '>' + postTitle + '</h3></a><span>'+ postAuthor + '</span><p>' + postContent + '</p></div>';
      document.write(item);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.universalmanual.com/feeds/posts/summary?orderby=published&max-results=500&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using blogger JSON feed, It is lightweight compared to XML feed (used in Atom and RSS) You can use `?alt=json` parameter to access json feed like this

```
https://www.universalmanual.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json
```

To parse JSON feed using javascript use `?alt=json-in-script` 
The following example shows the last post title from your blog

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    function get(json) {

        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<h2>" + json.feed.entry[0].title.$t + "</h2>";
    }
</script>

<script src="https://www.universalmanual.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=get"></script>
```

To show post image in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mycallback(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
          var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
          break;
        }
      }
      var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
      var postAuthor = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
      var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
      var entryShort = postSummary.substring(0,400);
      var entryEnd = entryShort.lastIndexOf(" ");
      var postContent = entryShort.substring(0, entryEnd) + '...';
      var postImage = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url.replace('s72-c/','s1600/');
      var item = '<div class="wrapper"><img src="' + postImage + '"/><h3><a href=' + postUrl + '>' + postTitle + '</h3></a><span>'+ postAuthor + '</span><p>' + postContent + '</p></div>';
      document.write(item);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.universalmanual.com/feeds/posts/summary?orderby=published&max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"></script>
```

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](https://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/10/introduction-to-blogger-json-feeds-and-blogger-data-api.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I update my post above by using your suggestion. But it didn't show the image in it. can you help me to fix it?

Comment: To get image url use `json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url` see the update

Comment: I Updated my post after adding thumbnail but thumbnails are too small. I want to use featured image or first image instead of the thumbnail. How to replace  thumbnail with image

Comment: Use `.replace('s72-c/','')` with postImage variable Try my answer

Comment: If you need more resolution  use `replace('s72-c/','s1600/')`

Comment: This is the actual image size

Comment: For additional reference on the solution (parsing the JSON feed directly from your Javascript), check out the Blogger API Documentation on this https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/getting_started#JSONP